# Qt Code signing cross-platform

Tags: qt

I'm about to deploy my application written in `Qt` and now want to sign the code to avoid the `Windows 8 smartscreen` as well as `identified developer` on OS X.

My application will be shipped to Mac and Windows.

Is there any cross-platform solution to this?

I've had a look at digicert extened validation (EV) it seems to be very easy to sign a Windows application.

What are my options here? I would like to avoid something to complicated.

Comment: Qt should be cross Platform. You must only re-build same code for these machines, but code should not be changed.

Comment: I was thinking about the code signing, is there a solution i can use on mac and win?

Comment: The "solution" you're looking for is a couple of lines added to the .pro file for each platform. I don't really see how it could be made cross-platform since the tools are native to each platform, the certificates are different, etc.

Comment: @KubaOber That sounds easy, what do I add? Where do I buy cert?

Comment: Actually, according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html), you can use one third-party code signing certificate on both Windows and OS X. The code signing tools are different on each platform, just read up on them and add the necessary targets and commands to your .pro file. On windows, you'd use the `signtool.exe`, on OS X it's something else. Keep in mind the goal: all of this has to go into the .pro file.

Answer (score 0):

See [Comodo Code Signing](http://www.comodo.com/business-security/code-signing-certificates/code-signing.php), in company which I work for we use it for Windows but as I can see it supports also MacOS.